# 07 Escalade - Unknown sensor

Tags: sensor, escalade

I'm chasing what appears to be a bad shock on my 2007 Escalade (AWD), and I found this... sensor?

It's a small, cylindrical widget on the end of what I assume is part of the wiring harness.

[image]

(My thumb is not missing, just bent out of the way.)

There's a Christmas tree clamp on it, but it's not obvious where it's supposed to be mounted. Initially, this was hanging down in the wheel well forward of the front, LH shock absorber.

Any thoughts? This is the one vehicle in the driveway for which I do not have the factory service manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kinda looks like the vent tube for the front differential. A picture of the top would help. Does it have any electrical terminals?

Comment: I'll grab another picture in a bit. By "top", do you mean the flat end (top of the cylinder)? It's a solid piece, no sign of a vent aperture of any kind.

Comment: Yeah, the top of the cylinder.  Can you follow the line where it goes?

Comment: @DavidLively - It looked like a vent to me as well. Trace it back to origin and see if it goes to your front diff.